# Sub that creates a new sheet opens VBA editor for a fraction of a second

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

I have a strange behaviour, with both Excel 2010 and Excel 2019 (both in Windows 10 64 bit).
I have a file with lots of VBA code and a certain Sub that creates a new sheet and copies data from two other sheets.
When this Sub is called it works as expected but, for a fraction of a second, Excel opens and then closes the VBA editor.
In slower PCs the phenomenon is much more visible.
Also, if I protect the VBA Code (Tools, VBA Project properties) the Sub doesn't work as expected.
I can't explain it, any help would be highly appreciated.

```
Sub ConfrontoSomme(ByVal Foglio1 As String, ByVal Foglio2 As String)
 
    On Error GoTo errore
    
    'se esiste già il foglio lo cancello
    

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    NomeFoglioDaCreare = "CONFRONTO SOMME"
    'ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Password:=" "
    Call DeleteSheet(NomeFoglioDaCreare)
    
    ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Password:=" "
    Sheets.Add(, ActiveSheet).Name = NomeFoglioDaCreare
    ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:=" "
    
    

    
    With ActiveWindow
                
        ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
        ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
        Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
        '.Zoom = 89

    End With
    
    
    
        If CustomZoom = False Then
            ActiveWindow.Zoom = 89
        Else
            ActiveWindow.Zoom = 110
        End If

    

    
    'cerco l'ultima riga della colonna "C" contenente un valore
    UltimaRiga1 = LastRowColumn(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Foglio1), "r", "c")
    UltimaRiga2 = LastRowColumn(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Foglio2), "r", "c")
    

    
    'lo rimetto a False in quanto il nuovo foglio è stato creato
    CreazioneConfrontoSomme = False
    
    
    'setto altezza prima riga:
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Range("A1").RowHeight = 10
    
    'CREO COLONNE PRIMA SOMMA
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Range("B2:D2").Merge
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Range("B2").Value = Foglio1
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Range("B2").Select
    
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 12611584
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 20
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    
    
    'copio intestazione con larghezza colonne e formattazione
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Foglio1).Range("B2:D3").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Range("B4:D5")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Foglio1).Range("B2:D3").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Range("B4:D5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                                                        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 1
            
    RowHght = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Foglio1).Range("B3").EntireRow.Height
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Range("B5").RowHeight = RowHght
    
    '+2 per differenza di riga tra foglio originario e il nuovo creato
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Foglio1).Range("B4:D" & UltimaRiga1).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Range("B6:D" & UltimaRiga1 + 2)

    
    '=========================================================================================


    'CREO COLONNE SECONDA SOMMA
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Range("F2:H2").Merge
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Range("F2").Value = Foglio2
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Range("F2").Select
    
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 12611584
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 20
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    

    
    
    'copio intestazione con larghezza colonne e formattazione
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Foglio2).Range("B2:D3").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Range("F4:H5")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Foglio2).Range("B2:D3").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Range("F4:H5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                                                        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            
    'COLONNA FORMULA DI CONFRONTO SX
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 25 'più larga per separare meglio le 2 sezioni
    
    'COLONNA FORMULA DI CONFRONTO SX
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Columns("I").ColumnWidth = 17
            
    'già fatto prima
    'RowHght = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Foglio1).Range("B3").EntireRow.Height
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Range("B5").RowHeight = RowHght
    
    '+2 per differenza di riga tra foglio originario e il nuovo creato
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Foglio2).Range("B4:D" & UltimaRiga2).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Range("F6:H" & UltimaRiga2 + 2)


    
    
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 12 '7.5
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 36
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 11
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 12
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 36
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 11
    
    
    
    'CREO LA FORMULA PER CERCARE I VALORI DELLA SOMMA A SINISTRA IN QUELLI A DESTRA
    CellaPartenza = "$G$6"
    CellaFine = "$G$" & UltimaRiga2 + 2
          
    For i = 6 To UltimaRiga1 + 2
        CellaPartenza2 = "$C" & i
        FormulaConfronto = "=If(CountIf(" & CellaPartenza & ":" & CellaFine & "," & CellaPartenza2 & ") <> 0, """", ""Non in " & """ & $F$2)"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Cells(i, 4).Formula = "" & FormulaConfronto & ""
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Cells(i, 4).Font.Size = 13
    Next i
            
            
    'CREO LA FORMULA PER CERCARE I VALORI DELLA SOMMA A DESTRA IN QUELLI A SINISTRA
    CellaPartenza = "$C$6"
    CellaFine = "$C$" & UltimaRiga1 + 2
          
    For i = 6 To UltimaRiga2 + 2
        CellaPartenza2 = "$G" & i
        FormulaConfronto = "=If(CountIf(" & CellaPartenza & ":" & CellaFine & "," & CellaPartenza2 & ") <> 0, """", ""Non in " & """ & $B$2)"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Cells(i, 8).Formula = "" & FormulaConfronto & ""
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Cells(i, 8).Font.Size = 13
    Next i
            
            
            
            
    'NEL FOGLIO CONFRONTO SOMME CREO IL PULSANTE PER ORDINARE DAL VALORE PIU' PICCOLO AL PIU' GRANDE
    If CustomZoom = False Then
        Set oOLE = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Left:=355, Top:=10, Width:=111, Height:=24)
    Else
        Set oOLE = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Left:=349.6, Top:=10, Width:=111, Height:=24)
    End If

    With oOLE
        .Object.Caption = "Ordina Min>Mag"       'SCRITTA CHE APPARE SUL PULSANTE
        .Name = "OrdinaMinMag"                   'NOME MACRO CREATA NEL CODICE SALVATO NEL FOGLIO (NON IN UN MODULO)
        .Object.BackColor = RGB(153, 211, 245)
        '.Object.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        .PrintObject = False
        .Object.Font.Name = "CALIBRI"
        .Object.Font.Size = 14
        '.Object.Font.Bold = True
    
    End With
    

    'NEL FOGLIO CONFRONTO SOMME CREO IL CODICE MACRO PER ORDINARE DAL VALORE PIU' PICCOLO AL PIU' GRANDE, ABBINATO AL PULSANTE
    'ad un certo punto ho dovuto scrivere una riga tutta di fila altrimenti appariva l'errore "troppo continuazioni di riga"
    
    'cambia solo da "Sort.SortFields.Add" a "Sort.SortFields.Add2"
    'Se > Excel 2010
    If Val(Application.Version) > 14 Then
    
    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).CodeName).CodeModule
        .InsertLines .CreateEventProc("Click", oOLE.Name) + 1, vbTab & _
        vbCrLf & vbTab & "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "Range(""C6:C305"").Select" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="" """ & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort.SortFields.Clear" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range(""C6:C305""), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".SetRange Range(""C6:C305"")" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".Header = xlGuess" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".MatchCase = False" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".Orientation = xlTopToBottom" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".SortMethod = xlPinYin" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".Apply" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "End With" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "Range(""G6:G305"").Select" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="" """ & vbCrLf & vbTab & "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort.SortFields.Clear" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range(""G6:G305""), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".SetRange Range(""G6:G305"")" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".Header = xlGuess" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".MatchCase = False" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".Orientation = xlTopToBottom" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".SortMethod = xlPinYin" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".Apply" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "End With" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Range(""A1"").Select" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Application.ScreenUpdating = True"
        Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
    End With
            
    Else
    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).CodeName).CodeModule
        .InsertLines .CreateEventProc("Click", oOLE.Name) + 1, vbTab & _
        vbCrLf & vbTab & "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "Range(""C6:C305"").Select" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="" """ & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort.SortFields.Clear" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(""C6:C305""), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".SetRange Range(""C6:C305"")" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".Header = xlGuess" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".MatchCase = False" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".Orientation = xlTopToBottom" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".SortMethod = xlPinYin" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".Apply" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "End With" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "Range(""G6:G305"").Select" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="" """ & vbCrLf & vbTab & "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort.SortFields.Clear" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(""G6:G305""), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".SetRange Range(""G6:G305"")" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".Header = xlGuess" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".MatchCase = False" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".Orientation = xlTopToBottom" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".SortMethod = xlPinYin" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".Apply" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "End With" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Range(""A1"").Select" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Application.ScreenUpdating = True"
        Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
    End With
            
    End If
            
            
    'NEL FOGLIO CONFRONTO SOMME CREO IL PULSANTE PER ORDINARE DAL VALORE PIU' GRANDE AL PIU' PICCOLO
    If CustomZoom = False Then
        Set oOLE = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Left:=355, Top:=50, Width:=111, Height:=24)
    Else
        Set oOLE = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Left:=349.6, Top:=48.6, Width:=111, Height:=24)
    End If

    With oOLE
        .Object.Caption = "Ordina Mag>Min"       'SCRITTA CHE APPARE SUL PULSANTE
        .Name = "OrdinaMagMin"                   'NOME MACRO CREATA NEL CODICE SALVATO NEL FOGLIO (NON IN UN MODULO)
        .Object.BackColor = RGB(153, 211, 245)
        '.Object.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        .PrintObject = False
        .Object.Font.Name = "CALIBRI"
        .Object.Font.Size = 14
        '.Object.Font.Bold = True
    
    End With
    

    'NEL FOGLIO CONFRONTO SOMME CREO IL CODICE MACRO PER ORDINARE DAL VALORE PIU' GRANDE AL PIU' PICCOLO, ABBINATO AL PULSANTE
    'ad un certo punto ho dovuto scrivere una riga tutta di fila altrimenti appariva l'errore "troppo continuazioni di riga"
    
    'cambia solo da "Sort.SortFields.Add" a "Sort.SortFields.Add2"
    'Se > Excel 2010
    If Val(Application.Version) > 14 Then
    
    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).CodeName).CodeModule
        .InsertLines .CreateEventProc("Click", oOLE.Name) + 1, vbTab & _
        vbCrLf & vbTab & "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "Range(""C6:C305"").Select" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="" """ & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort.SortFields.Clear" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range(""C6:C305""), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".SetRange Range(""C6:C305"")" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".Header = xlGuess" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".MatchCase = False" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".Orientation = xlTopToBottom" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".SortMethod = xlPinYin" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".Apply" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "End With" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "Range(""G6:G305"").Select" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="" """ & vbCrLf & vbTab & "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort.SortFields.Clear" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range(""G6:G305""), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".SetRange Range(""G6:G305"")" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".Header = xlGuess" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".MatchCase = False" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".Orientation = xlTopToBottom" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".SortMethod = xlPinYin" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".Apply" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "End With" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Range(""A1"").Select" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Application.ScreenUpdating = True"
        Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
    End With
            
    Else
    
    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).CodeName).CodeModule
        .InsertLines .CreateEventProc("Click", oOLE.Name) + 1, vbTab & _
        vbCrLf & vbTab & "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "Range(""C6:C305"").Select" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="" """ & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort.SortFields.Clear" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(""C6:C305""), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".SetRange Range(""C6:C305"")" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".Header = xlGuess" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".MatchCase = False" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".Orientation = xlTopToBottom" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".SortMethod = xlPinYin" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        ".Apply" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "End With" & vbCrLf & vbTab & _
        "Range(""G6:G305"").Select" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="" """ & vbCrLf & vbTab & "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort.SortFields.Clear" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(""G6:G305""), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(""CONFRONTO SOMME"").Sort" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".SetRange Range(""G6:G305"")" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".Header = xlGuess" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".MatchCase = False" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".Orientation = xlTopToBottom" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".SortMethod = xlPinYin" & vbCrLf & vbTab & ".Apply" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "End With" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Range(""A1"").Select" & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Application.ScreenUpdating = True"
        Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
    End With
    
    End If
    
    'per non avere nessuna cella selezionata visibile
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Range("A500").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NomeFoglioDaCreare).Protect Password:=" "
    ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:=" "



errore:
    'Call DeleteSheet(NomeFoglioDaCreare)
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You would probably need to show the code to get any help with this. Hopefully there is not a ton of it.

Comment: Fascinating, short run fix try using Application.ScreenUpdating= False

Comment: I updated the post with the code and I already use Application.ScreenUpdating= False.  
I don't really explain it.

Comment: I found a post [here](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/502085-keep-vba-window-hidden.html) but it didn't work for me. Other solutions I found involved moving the window off screen but they looked pretty fragile.